Can I dynamically add or remove LoRA weights in the transformer library like diffusers
I see that in the diffuser library, there is this feature to dynamically add and remove LoRA weights based on this article https://github.com/huggingface/blog/blob/main/lora-adapters-dynamic-loading.md · GitHub and using the load_lora_weights and fuse_lora_weights. I want to know if I can do something similar with LoRA for transformers too?

You can use peft.

how I can dynamically load only the lora weights in peft, I understand the backend in the example I gave is also peft but I couldn't find the same lora_weight function for loading lora weigths

In PEFT, when you create or load an adapter, you give it a name.
Then you can enable the adapter(s) of your choice dynamically by name with https://huggingface.co/docs/peft/package_reference/lora#peft.LoraModel.set_adapter
See the example of how to do this here:
https://huggingface.co/docs/peft/en/developer_guides/lora#load-adapters

Please include the relevant code in our answer itself. Link-only-answers-are-not-good-answers.

That changes what exactly? Let me just quote the important part: "When someone goes on Stack Exchange, the question "answer" should actually contain an answer. Not just a bunch of directions towards the answer."
